# Using a Decision Tree to build a Recommendations Application

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

First of all, my apologies if I am not following some of the best practices of this site, as you will see, my home is mostly MSE (math stack exchange).

I am currently working on a project where I build a vacation recommendation system. The initial idea was somewhat akin to 20 questions: We ask the user certain questions, such as "Do you like museums?", "Do you like architecture", "Do you like nightlife" etc., and then based on these answers decide for the user their best vacation destination. We answer these questions based on keywords scraped from websites, and the decision tree we would implement would allow us to effectively determine the next question to ask a user. However, we are having some difficulties with the implementation. Some examples of our difficulties are as follows:

There are issues with granularity of questions. For example, to say that a city is good for "nature-lovers" is great, but this does not mean much. Nature could involve say, hot, sunny and wet vacations for some, whereas for others, nature could involve a brisk hike in cool woods. Fortunately, the API we are currently using provides us with a list of attractions in a city, down to a fairly granular level (for example, it distinguishes between different watersport activities such as jet skiing, or white water rafting). My question is: do we need to create some sort of hiearchy like:

- nature-> (Ocean,Mountain,Plains) (Mountain->Hiking,Skiing,...)

or would it be best to simply include the bottom level results (the activities themselves) and just ask questions regarding those? I only ask because I am unfamiliar with exactly how the classification is done and the final output produced. Is there a better sort of structure that should be used?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a decision tree is a great idea for this problem.  It might be an idea to group your granular activities, and for the "nature lovers" category list a number of different climate types: Dry and sunny, coastal, forests, etc and have subcategories within them.

For the activities, you could make a category called watersports, sightseeing, etc.  It sounds like your dataset is more granular than you want your decision tree to be, but you can just keep dividing that granularity down into more categories on the tree until you reach a level you're happy with.  It might be an idea to include images too, of each place and activity.  Maybe even without descriptive text.

Comment: Got it thank you. My only issue with this is the amount of "hard coding" needed, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: So I've taken your advice and split things up. Now I have big bins (like nature for example) and small sub-bins like Ocean_Nature (Referring to natural attractions that have oceans in them. Once I've done this, I'd like to assign a score to each location. I was thinking that for each place, we count the top30 attractions (as said by a site like tripadvisor) and then classify each one as OceanNature, Nature etc. Then, for each place, its score for the given bin is the number of places it has in a certain bin.

Comment: Is this sort of redundancy (with categories and subcategories) bad? Or will the tree be able to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Bins and sub bins are a good idea, as is the nature, ocean_nature thing.

I was thinking more about your problem last night, TripAdvisor would be a good idea.  What I would do is, take the top 10 items in trip advisor and categorize them by type.

Or, maybe your tree narrows it down to 10 cities.  You would rank those cities according to popularity or distance from the user.

I’m not sure how to decide which city would be best for watersports, etc.  You could even have cities pay to be top of the list.

Comment: Thanks. Currently we take the top 30 attractions for each city, and categorize them based on types. We count the number of items in each city for each type (for example, we count al the paris museums) and then given paris a museum score based on this count. We do this for a long list of cities. Each city then is a vector with a city name, and then scores for each category with some repeats (subcategories and categories). Once we're done computing scores for everywhere we'll throw it into sklearn